# Which user input devices can be used beside Razer Hydra?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I can see from the tutorials section that the Razer Hydra can be used with Gazebo, but what about others such as playstation, xbox or other console-agnostic controllers?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17154/which-user-input-devices-can-be-used-beside-razer-hydra?/) by [craig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3779/craig/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-09-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Not exactly a "controller", but you can use a [SpaceNav](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-requests/1168/integrated-space-navigator-joystick/diff) 3d mouse without much extra setup.

One common way to use joysticks is through [ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/joy/Tutorials/ConfiguringALinuxJoystick). It would be nice to have more out-of-the-box plugins to use joysticks directly with Gazebo...

Fun fact, I recently discovered that those "presentation laser pointer remotes" register just like keyboard keystrokes, and they can be used with the [KeyboardGUIPlugin](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/plugins/KeyboardGUIPlugin.hh).

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1